# Look for pydoc analog for java for reading docs from command line

Tags: java, emacs, elisp, javadoc, pydoc

Pydoc can produce nice docs for Python module/function/class for reading from command line.

This tools [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html) seems does not provide such capabilities.

I use Emacs and look for ability quickly get docs about standard java library without leaving Emacs.

If such utility exist I can integrate in to Emacs...

Also I think it is nice read javadoc from Bash...

**PS.** For example I expect that utility extract docs from existen java installation without specifing path to it (from **JAVA_HOME**, or **PATH** without javadoc.zip only from src.zip which come with all **JDK** installation)...

Comment: I expect extract some tips from http://javadochelp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

While reading a bit about clojure -lisp on JVM-, I came accross this solution for what you need: http://cynojure.posterous.com/clojure-emacs-and-javadocs.

Comment: This is good tips, but require work to make all done. For example I expect that utility extract docs from existen java installation without specifing path to it (without javadoc.zip only from src.zip which come with all java installation)...